# Qemu shows a black screen

Tags: linux, arm, virtual-machine, qemu

When the run following command on the teriminal

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel /home/<name>/linux-3.10.10/arch/arm/boot/uImage
```

A window with black screen will be opened and remain blank with no messages, but I am expecting Kernel messages on this screen. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Does serial work? And can you try with VNC instead of SDL? I found an SDL-specific bug at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1778182

Answer (score 4):

You have no console. Use '-append "console=tty1"' as shown below. Append gives command line arguments to kernel. Also, after the console issue is fixed, you will probably see a need for a root filesystem; many options exist there, I use a previously-mounted disk image, I have shown a commandline with both below.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel /home/<name>/linux-3.10.10/arch/arm/boot/uImage -append "console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootfstype=ext3" -drive file=disk.img,if=sd
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and it has changed nothing for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to emulate a Raspberry Pi, use follow the advice in Joe Kul's answer, but instead of `tty1`, use `ttyAMA0` instead.