# Just black screen after running Qemu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtualization, qemu

I have just installed QEMU and compiled linux kernel with ARM support but when I run below command

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel /home/arit/QEMU/linux-3.8.4/arch/arm/boot/uImage -append "console=tty1"
```

I could only see Black screen ,I also tried what is being suggested in below thread

[Qemu shows a black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673582/qemu-shows-a-black-screen)

But still it didn't work.

Following is the output of make command which I run to compile kernel Source

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage -s

```
 Image Name:   Linux-3.8.4
 Created:      Tue Dec 24 12:49:07 2013
 Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
 Data Size:    4406472 Bytes = 4303.20 kB = 4.20 MB
 Load Address: fffffff2
 Entry Point:  fffffff2
```

Are Load and Entry points OK here?

Comment: Try it with the option -sdl. I've never had the gtk interface work.

Comment: @Bandrami Would you be more specific of -sdl option.How do I use it?

Comment: It's an option to qemu, like -m. Just add -sdl to the end of your qemu command.

Comment: Does serial work? And can you try with VNC instead of SDL? I found an SDL-specific bug at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1778182

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No your Load and Entry points ARE NOT CORRECT. typically below is load and entry address

```
Image Name:   Linux-3.9.0
Created:      Thu Dec 26 09:50:57 2013
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    1908056 Bytes = 1863.34 kB = 1.82 MB
Load Address: 00008000
Entry Point:  00008000
```

Moreover if you try with your command, kernel will `be panic` in the absence of rootfs. initrd parameters are missing. Also you might be missing some configuration while building kernel.

Try these steps:

1)`make  ARCH=arm distclean`

2)`make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig`

3)`make ARCH=arm menuconfig`

here you need to enable below feature.

`Kernel Features  --->`
                   `[*] Use the ARM EABI to compile the kernel. (enable this).`

4)`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage`

5)`qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -append "console=tty1"`

Here you will get console saying that kernel panic.
to avoid this pass your rootfs parameter.

I guess you built rootfs from busybox if so try below command to boot system completely

6)`qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram mem=128M rdinit=/sbin/init"  -serial stdio.`

Comment: Thanks Vinay for your answer.I tried changing Load Address and Entry address to 00008000 and 00008000 using mkimage command but it didn't work out. Also I already had enabled the ARM EABI from kernel Features.Do I have to supply Entry and Load Address through kernel config file?

Comment: Dont try with mkimage ..just run make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage .. it ll take care @ d end of compilation to add entry address

Comment: But this is how I did it earlier also.

Comment: One more thing i observe in ur image size too large .. have done too many changes in default confuguration .. 1st try with ma above steps with default configuration if it works f9 .. de go with enabling your requirements

Comment: Thanks Vinay,I tried your steps and its working ok,We were missing make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig step earlier.Is this config file is responsible for setting up entry and load address of uImage or how load and entry address are set up

Comment: @vinayHunachyal How do you build your rootfs?

Comment: I followed your steps and it doesn't work. Still black screen for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you asking `Is this config file is responsible for setting up entry and load address of uImage`

Yes `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage`

this command is responsible for loading entry point.
How ?
--->In kernel source code open  `vi scripts/mkuboot.sh`

here check `MKIMAGE=$(type -path "${CROSS_COMPILE}mkimage")`

the script will take care to call `scripts/Makefile.lib.`

here in code

MKIMAGE := $(srctree)/scripts/mkuboot.sh

```
  UIMAGE_ARCH ?= $(SRCARCH)
  UIMAGE_COMPRESSION ?= $(if $(2),$(2),none)
  UIMAGE_OPTS-y ?=
  UIMAGE_TYPE ?= kernel
  UIMAGE_LOADADDR ?= arch_must_set_this
  UIMAGE_ENTRYADDR ?= $(UIMAGE_LOADADDR)
  UIMAGE_NAME ?= 'Linux-$(KERNELRELEASE)'
  UIMAGE_IN ?= $<
  UIMAGE_OUT ?= $@
```

-->

if the user doesnt mention LOADADDR in command line the address is took from below
UIMAGE_LOADADDR ?= arch_must_set_this

```
ifneq ($(LOADADDR),)
UIMAGE_LOADADDR=$(LOADADDR)
else
   ifeq ($(CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM),y)
   UIMAGE_LOADADDR=$(CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM_TEXT)
  else
UIMAGE_LOADADDR=$(ZRELADDR)
endif
endif
```

`UIMAGE_LOADADDR=$(ZRELADDR)` --> this variable responsible for loading entry address

the valve $(ZRELADDR) is took from board specific for in our case versatile so

`arch/arm/mach-versatile/Makefile.boot`

here

```
   zreladdr-y   += 0x00008000
params_phys-y   := 0x00000100
initrd_phys-y   := 0x00800000
```

This is how in kernel scripts are automated when  `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- uImage`

executed.

Comment: Thanks Vinay for the detailed answered,would you also let know the ise of make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig command?

Comment: @singh sorry i dint get you can u repeat ur query pls

Comment: just want to know what make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig will do?

Answer (score 1):

For SINGH's question

`what make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig will do?`

1) when you compiling kernel the 1st question is for which architecture are you building?

suppose if you are building for x86 architecture you no need to give ARCH=x86 ,by default 
it takes x86 and for x86 you dont need any cross-compiler , native compiler takes care compiling . You can verify it in Top-level Makefile.

if u give command ` make menuconfig' then by default it takes /boot/config-x.x.x this is for x86.

So present configuration of system is written to .config from /boot/config-x.x.x

But what for arm architecture which you are building on x86 architecture having native compiler?

here you should need cross-compiler tool cahin to compile kernel for ARM.

so from this background its clear y u need to provide ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE variables.?

when `make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig`

Top-level makefile read this command that architecture is arm copies versatile_defconfig which is present in arch/arm/configs/versatile_defconfig

and writes to .config.

Here you ll get minimum configuration ,Next using menuconfig you enable your required things.

Comment: Ok fine @Vinay and versatile_defconfig is config file for versatile Physical board,right?

Comment: ya its for versatile board