# Cross Compiling using a config file

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

Using Config file will shorten the process of compiling without answering yes or no to many features of the build.

However in this case,

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} config
```

I still get many questions,seems like it's not working for the script file.

Is that the right syntax for reading in that config file?

Comment: What does your Makefile look like? What error messages are you getting? Your command line there tells make to build the target "config" and sets the variables `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE`, it doesn't read from a config file.

Comment: please have look @ this your syntax is wrong. since u need give some defult configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763344/just-black-screen-after-running-qemu/20779114#20779114