# QEMU blank screen issue

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu

I build and flashed mainline kernel using

1)`make ARCH=arm distclean`

2)`make ARCH=arm bcm_defconfig`

3)`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- LOADADDR=0x00008000 uImage`

4)`qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init"`

QEMU shows a blank screen nothing in it. Could someone please help?

Do I need to change the machine? If yes, please let me know which machine?

Comment: for which board or platform your kernel built? since defconfig says its for broadcom and you qemu command says machine is versatile pb. please update your question for which board r u trying?

Comment: check this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763344/just-black-screen-after-running-qemu/20779114#20779114

Comment: @vinayhunachyal yes, above is wrong, I used a wrong board for broadcom  config. Neither I know which one should be the correct one. I don't want to you versatile, so which board should go with broadcom config?

Comment: is your target is broadcom i.e RPI (raspberry pi) you want emulate with qemu?

Comment: To emulate RPI on qemu is not a straight forward as qemu doest not support BCM platform ,its tricky thing to do,anyway it can be done with qemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emulate RPI on qemu is not a straight forward as qemu doest not support BCM platform ,its tricky thing to do,anyway it can be done with qemu –  vinay hunachyal Mar 19 at 5:15

Comment: how it can be done? is there any specific qemu branch? does it need a custom kernel?